# C++ "Exceção lançada: violação de acesso de leitura."

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>     
using namespace std;

struct review {
    string text;
    string date;
};

void acessaRegistro(int i) {
    review* reg = new review;
    ifstream file;
    file.open("test.txt", ios::binary);
    if (file) {
        file.seekg(i * sizeof(review), ios::beg);
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(reg), sizeof(review));
        cout << reg->text;
        file.close();
    }
    delete reg;
}

void geraArquivoBinario()
{
    ofstream arq("test.txt", ios::binary);
    review x;
    x.text = "asdasdasd";
    x.date = "qweqweqwe";
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++)
    {
        arq.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&x), sizeof(review));
    }

    arq.close();
}


int main() {

    geraArquivoBinario();
    acessaRegistro(2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Estou tentando fazer um programa que escreve um conjunto de "reviews" em um arquivo binário, e depois lê um determinado registro. O programa parece funcionar, mas no fim sempre ocorre uma exceção: "Exceção gerada em 0x00007FF628E58C95 em trabalho.exe: 0xC0000005: violação de acesso ao ler o local 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF." Como posso resolver? Obrigado!

Comment: Aqui `review* reg = new review;` essa estrutura `new review` ela está sendo alocada na stack e quando a função termina  a estrutura sai do escopo então havendo duas tentativa de desalocação.  Apenas remova a linha `delete reg;`

Comment: Não parece funcionar não. Não pode simplesmente gravar a string em disco. São objetos complicados. `sizeof()` da string não é o "`strlen()`" o `size()` da string. Escreveu praticamente um programa em C, mas mesmo em C não funcionaria. Você precisa ter um formato para gerar os registros, que tem tamanho variável. Ou não tem? Usou 9 letras no exemplo. Qual a razão de testar o programa com 1 milhão de registros? Note que C++ tem separador de dígitos e pode escrever `1'000'000`

Answer (score 1):

Para gravar e ler do disco você precisa de um método. Isso se chama em geral `serialize`. Não pode simplesmente gravar as strings no disco. Se são strings de tamanho fixo não há dificuldade e você pode navegar como em um array, usando coisas como `ftell()` e `fseek()`.

Mas para strings de tamanho supostamente variável você tem que gravar e ler registros, claro, de tamanho variável. Não pode usar `sizeof()` ou `size()` ou `strlen()`.

Vou deixar um exemplo com uma função de auto-teste e que você pode usar facilmente para seu caso ou qualquer caso. É o comum: o `Registro` é o que você grava no disco. O `Review` é a (sua) classe a ser serializada.

A técnica: o simples: um header com o tamanho precede o registro no disco. Cada string é precedida por um header com o tamanho, como em Pascal ou TCP/IP ou todo lugar.

#### `struct` `Review`

```
struct Review
{
    string text;
    string date;
    Review();
    Review(const char* txt, const char* date);
};
```

Criei assim para poder chamar direto com algo assim

```
    Review   uma   = Review("Stack", "Overflow");
```

#### `struct` `Registro`

```
struct Registro
{
    uint64_t       tamanho[3];  // 8 bytes
    unsigned char* dado;
    Registro(Review&);
    ~Registro();
    Review Registro::converte();
};
```

Os tamanhos são para ajudar na conferência. `char*` é o prático nesses casos. `converte()` faz o óbvio: retorna um `Review` com o conteúdo que estava no `Registro`. Transformar um `Review` em `Registro` acontece automaticamente ao declarar um Registro: ou cria com `text` e `date` em branco ou cria a partir de uma `Review` que já exista, como no caso do exemplo abaixo.

`uint64_t` é o tipo portável para 64bits sem sinal de `<cstdint>`

No disco vai gravar

```
[|total em bytes|total de text|text|total de date|date]
```

Para cada review na memória.

Esse é o código para o exemplo:

```
int main(void)
{
    Review   uma   = Review("Stack", "Overflow");
    Registro teste = Registro(uma);
    Review   unzip = teste.converte();
    return 0;
}
```

Esse é o programa de teste. `uma` é a `Review`. `teste` é um `Registro` criado a partir de `uma`. `unzip` é o retorno de `converte()` e deve ter as mesmas strings `text` e `date`.

Para facilitar deixei um `cout` no construtor de `Review` então já vai ver isso na tela.

#### Saida do exemplo

```
    criada Review:
        "Stack"
        "Overflow"


    criada Review:
        "Stack"
        "Overflow"
```

Acho que entendeu. O primeiro par é da criação de `um` e o outro da criação de `unzip`, no programa acima.

#### O código

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
#pragma pack(show)
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Review
{
    string text;
    string date;
    Review();
    Review(const char* txt, const char* date);
};

struct Registro
{
    uint64_t       tamanho[3];  // 4 bytes
    unsigned char* dado;
    Registro(Review&);
    ~Registro();
    Review Registro::converte();
};

int main()
{
    Review   uma   = Review("Stack", "Overflow");
    Registro teste = Registro(uma);
    Review   unzip = teste.converte();
    return 0;
}

// Review

Review::Review() : Review("", ""){};

Review::Review(const char* txt, const char* date)
    : text(string(txt)), date(string(date))
{
    cout << "\n    criada Review:\n\t\"" << text << "\"\n\t\"" << date
         << "\"\n\n";
}

// Registro

Registro::Registro(Review& rvw)
{
    uint64_t offset = 0;
    tamanho[0] =
        rvw.date.size() + rvw.text.size() + 3 * sizeof(uint64_t) + 2;
    dado = (unsigned char*)new char[tamanho[0]]{0};
    // hdr0
    memcpy(dado, &tamanho[0], sizeof(uint64_t));
    offset += sizeof(uint64_t);
    // hdr1
    tamanho[1] = 1 + rvw.text.size();
    memcpy(dado + offset, &tamanho[1], sizeof(uint64_t));
    offset += sizeof(uint64_t);
    // string 1
    memcpy(dado + offset, rvw.text.c_str(), rvw.text.size());
    offset += tamanho[1];

    // hdr2
    tamanho[2] = 1 + rvw.date.size();
    memcpy(dado + offset, &tamanho[2], sizeof(uint64_t));
    offset += sizeof(uint64_t);
    // string 2
    memcpy(dado + offset, rvw.date.c_str(), rvw.date.size());
    offset += tamanho[2];
}

Registro::~Registro() { delete[] dado; };

Review Registro::converte()
{
    // hdr 0
    uint64_t size   = 0;
    uint64_t offset = 0;
    memcpy(&size, dado + offset, sizeof(uint64_t));
    offset += sizeof(uint64_t);
    // hdr 1
    memcpy(&size, dado + offset, sizeof(uint64_t));
    offset += sizeof(uint64_t);
    // str 1
    char* buffer1 = (char*)new char[size];
    memcpy(buffer1, dado + offset, size);
    offset += size;  // copiou a primeira
    // hdr 2
    memcpy(&size, dado + offset, sizeof(uint64_t));
    offset += sizeof(uint64_t);
    // str 2
    char* buffer2 = (char*)new char[size];
    memcpy(buffer2, dado + offset, size);
    offset += size;  // copiou a segunda
    Review uma(buffer1, buffer2);
    delete[] buffer1;
    delete[] buffer2;
    return uma;
}
```

Para ler basta ler do disco para uma instância de `Registro` e usar converte para criar a `Review` correspondente.

Escreva de volta se tiver dificuldade com isso.